# Laberinto en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
// Crear la funcion 'direcciones':
// La funcion debe retornar un string de los movimientos Norte(N), Sur(S), Este(E), Oeste(O)
// que se deben realizar, para llegar al destino de un laberinto dado.
//

//     N: 'pared',
//     S: { // direccion = "S"
//         N: 'pared',
//         S: 'pared',
//         E: { // direccion = "SE"
//             N: 'destino', // direccion = "SEN"
//             S: 'pared',
//             E: 'pared',
//             O: 'pared'

// El retorno de la funcion 'direcciones' debe ser 'SEN', ya que el destino se encuentra
```

les agradeceria que pudieran ayudarme a resolver este algoritmo ya que yo intente de la manera que les dejare abajo de este mensaje, pero no me da los resultados esperados, muchas gracias:

```
function direcciones(laberinto, direccion = null) {
  let arr = [];
  for (const prop in laberinto){
    if(typeof laberinto[prop] === 'object'){
      arr.push(laberinto[prop][direccion]);
      laberinto[prop].direcciones(laberinto, direccion);
    }
    else if (laberinto[prop] === 'destino')aray.push(laberinto[prop][direccion]);
  } 
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hay poca información en tu pregunta, pues genera a su vez muchas otras como ¿buscas un algoritmo recursivo?, ¿pueden existir múltiples destinos?, ¿te vale encontrar cualquier camino o necesitas el más corto?, etc...

Una solución clásica es un algoritmo de búsqueda no informada. Te dejo una versión no recursiva que admite caminos alternativos y caminos sin salida.

#### El código

```js
function direcciones(laberinto) {
    const aExplorar = [['', laberinto]];

    while (aExplorar.length != 0) {
        const [camino, objeto] = aExplorar.shift()

        for (let [direccion, casilla] of Object.entries(objeto)) {
            if (casilla == 'destino') {
                return camino + direccion;
            }

            if (casilla != 'pared') {
                aExplorar.push([camino + direccion, casilla])
            }
        }
    }

    return "" // Retornamos vacío si no hay camino
}
```

#### La explicación

Nos interesa tener un registro de todos los objetos (es decir, esas casillas que no son destino ni pared y que tienen otras direcciones definidas, osea, cuando son objetos)

```js
const aExplorar = [['', laberinto]]
```

En este array iremos almacenando cada objeto que nos encontremos junto a todo el camino que hay que seguir para llegar hasta el (el camino acumulado). Comienza siendo el laberinto en sí con un camino vacío.

```js
while (aExplorar.length != 0) { ... }
```

Continuaremos todo el algoritmo mientras quede algo que explorar.

```js
    const [camino, objeto] = aExplorar.shift()
```

En cada iteración **extraemos** uno de esos pares camino-objeto de la lista para recorrerlo. El método `shift()` de los arrays extrae por delante, pero en también puedes usar pop() para extrar por el último. Según si extraes por delante o por detrás, estarías usando una [búsqueda en anchura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_anchura) o [en profundidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_profundidad) respectivamente.

*Por cierto, por si eres nuevo en esto, la forma en la que extraigo el camino y el objeto del array de 2 elementos camino-objeto es mediante [desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Básicamente es una forma rápida y bonita de crear dos variables con la posición [0] y [1] del array.*

Y finalmente

```js
        for (let [direccion, casilla] of Object.entries(objeto)) {
            if (casilla == 'destino') {
                return camino + direccion;
            }

            if (casilla != 'pared') {
                aExplorar.push([camino + direccion, casilla])
            }
        }
```

Para cada una de las entradas del objeto (pares direccion-casilla), si alguna resulta ser el destino terminamos devolviendo el camino más esta última dirección.

Si entre ellos encontramos otro objeto que tenemos que explorar (otro camino), lo metemos en la lista de objetos a recorrer, y se repite el proceso.

Comment: Justo justo.. es una pregunta duplicada ;)

Comment: @gbianchi vaya, con lo que me lo había currado. Había visto esa pregunta pero ni entré en ella, ya que habla de recursividad. En esta no indica nada de recursividad, al menos tiene una respuesta alternativa.